# Cyclic quadrilateral and trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

> A circle with diameter the minor base $CD$ of a trapezium $ABCD$ intersects its diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ in, respectively, their midpoints $M$ and $N$. The lines $DM$ and $CN$ intersect in $P$ and $AC$ and $BD$ intersect in $H$. Show that $AD=CD=BC$ and $HP \perp AB$.

[image]

$DMNC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and $CD||MN$, thus $DMNC$ is an isosceles trapezoid. Therefore, $CM=DN$ and $AC=BD$. Now I am trying to show $AD=CD$. $\angle DCM$ is inscribed and it's equal to $\angle DNM$ but I don't see how to compare it with $\angle CAD$. How is this done? For the second part of the problem, I tried to show that $HO$ passes through $P$ ($HO \perp CD$ because $\triangle CDH$ is isosceles and if we show $P \in HO$ we are done).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $DM\perp AC$ and $M$ is a midpoint of $AC$, we obtain $AD=DC$.

Can you end it now?

Since  $DMNC$ is an isosceles trapezoid, we obtain:
$$\measuredangle PMN=\measuredangle PDC=\measuredangle PCD=\measuredangle PNM,$$
which gives $$PM=PN.$$
Also, $$\Delta MDN\cong\Delta NCM,$$ which gives $$\measuredangle HMN=\measuredangle HNM,$$ which gives $$HM=HN,$$ which says that $PMHN$ is a kite, which says $$PH\perp MN.$$
About a kite see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry)

Comment: Yes. Thank you! $DM$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AC$.

Comment: @Andrew Rogers You are welcome!

Comment: Now I am trying to show that $HP \perp AB$ $(H = AC \cap BD)$. Is this true for all cases, because I can't prove it?

Comment: @Andrew Rogers Yes it's true because $HM=HN$ and $PM=PN.$ It's true if $AD=BC,$ which we got.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why it's true iff $HM=HN$ and $PM=PN$.

Comment: @Andrew Rogers In the general it's not true, of course. But with our given it's true.

Comment: @Andrew Rogers We got that $AD=DC=CB,$ which gives $AD=BC$, $PD=PC$ and from here $PN=PM.$

Comment: $HO \perp CD$ because $\triangle CDH$ is isosceles and $HO$ is median and height. How do we get that $HO$ passes through $P$?

Comment: Can I finish it from here? This was my first thought.

Comment: @Andrew Rogers Yes, you can. I am ready to show if you want. See my previous comment.

Comment: Yes. I would be very grateful if you can show me. I prefer to finish my own ideas. :)

Comment: @Andrew Rogers Can you open another topic with your new problem and with your attempts? Because it's really another problem and we can give chance to someone else to solve your problem.

Comment: I edited the post.